# Setup and Use Gherkin Android Studio

Tags: android, testing, cucumber, gherkin

as a part of a project I'm supposed to write test in Gherkin for my android app, to test features. I installed the Gherkin-Plugin in Android Studio (browse Repositories).

Now how do I use it? Where can I edit the feature files and run them against the app in the emulator?

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to try this library:
https://github.com/mauriciotogneri/green-coffee

You just need to import it and then you will be able to run your tests written in Gherkin.